# Monotouch Dialog Reflection Date element

Tags: api, reflection, dialog, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use Monotouch Dialog reflection API to bind to a class.

I have the following in my class:

[Entry("Birth Date")]
public DateTime BirthDate;

When this renders,  it renders as a DateTime,  which I suppose it expected.

Is there anyway to force this to be a date only

Thanks, 
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have read the documentation.

You can get a Date only selection by decorating the field with

[Date]  instead of [Entry(....